# Adding Items to An Array In an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object called `featureSet`.

Inside of `featureSet` there are many items, including an array called `features`, which contains other array, `attributes`.

I can add a new array inside of `featureSet.features.attributes` by doing the following within a `for loop`

```
featureSet.features[i].attributes.NEWITEM= [NEWITEM_ARRAY];
```

And when I use `console.log(featureSet)`, I can see that the items are there.

When I use `var test = JSON.stringify(featureSet`), however, only the original `featureSet` is returned.

How can I circumvent this so that when I call JSON.stringify, the new items are there as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem? Sounds like you need to wait for the asynchronous population to complete

Comment: attributes is an array but you add new property NEWITEM to it as if it is an object?

Comment: Yea need to see the code it could be a number of things..

Comment: @TarekEssam - I think you're correct. Attributes is an array of arrays. NEW ITEM would be an array as well. What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you do is close to:

```
let arr = []
console.log(arr) // []
arr.push(1)
console.log(arr) // [1]
arr.abc = 2
console.log(arr.abc) // 2
arr.push(3)
console.log(arr) // [1, 3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)) // '[1, 3]'
console.log(arr.abc) // 2
```

`JSON.stringify` loops through array props with the help of `Symbol.iterator`. Your properties do not have positive integer indexes, that's why they are ignored. There is an example on MDN as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

One more example to consider (continues the one above):

```
arr[7] = 7
console.log(arr) // [1, 3, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 7]
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)) // "[1,3,null,null,null,null,null,7]"
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I circumvent this so that when I call JSON.stringify, the new items are there as well?

You are trying to append attributes to an **array**, which will not work.

You can only append attributes to an **object**.

```js
/* the original feature set */
const featureSet = {
 features: [
   {feature: 'color',
     attributes: {}}, // this is an object, not an array
    {feature: 'shape',
      attributes: []}    // this is an array as per original scenario
  ]
}

/* adding attributes to an object succeeds */
featureSet.features[0].attributes.NEWITEM = ['this', 'was', 'appended'];

/* adding attributes to an array quietly fails */
featureSet.features[1].attributes.NEWITEM = ['this', 'was', 'not', 'appended'];


const featureSetAsJSONString = JSON.stringify(featureSet)
console.log(featureSetAsJSONString) // notice that feature[0] is as expected, but [1] isn't
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
featureSet.features[i].attributes.push({NEWITEM: [NEWITEM_ARRAY]})
```